# Props passed by a parent component doing a map are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React + JS in an app to render news of the NYTimes (https://developer.nytimes.com/). Well, the matter is that I want to render the most viewed in the last 7 days, but organized through categories or sections. And I have the problem with the rendering of my sections.

Here `my app.js` component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ListOfSections from "./components/ListOfSections";
import getSections from "./services/getSections";

import  Navbar  from "./shared/Navbar/Navbar";

function App() {

  const [section, setSection] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSections().then(sections=>setSection(sections));  
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <ListOfSections section={section}></ListOfSections>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here my `ListOfSections` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Section from './Section';

export default function ListOfSections ({section}) {

  return (
    <div className="container_list_sections mt-4 ml-4">
        {     
            section.map(({section})=> 
            
                <Section 
                    section={section}
                />
            )
        }
    </div>
  )


};
```

And here my `Section` component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Section ({section}) {

  return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="section-container mr-4">{section}</h1>
    </div>
  )


};
```

Well, the problem is when I do `console.log(section)` in the `Section` component, it returns me `undefined`. But if I do `console.log(section)` in `ListOfSections` component, it has received the information of the props. So... why when I am passing the prop `section` from `ListOfSections` to `Section`, is it undefined? Where is it the error? I dont understand. The result for the moment is this one:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Thanks :)

Comment: Please try to add a breakpoint in your 'then' and see if you get an array. In addition, when you use map in React, you need to pass a key in order to let react knows what changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` should look as follows:

```
const [sections, setSections] = useState([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
    getSections().then(sections=>setSections(sections));  
  }, [])
```

When you get data back it seems to be an array of `sections` so it should be a plural.

So when you pass `sections` down as a prop, it should be:

```
<ListOfSections sections={sections}/>
```

Which then allows you to map in `<ListOfSections>`

```
export default function ListOfSections ({sections}) {

  return (
    <div className="container_list_sections mt-4 ml-4">
        {     
            sections.map(section => 
            
                <Section 
                    section={section}
                />
            )
        }
    </div>
  )


};
```

For maps, you should also set a `key`, you can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)